# How to retrieve all positions of a profile, including past ones

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, profile

I have tried several things to be able to retrieve all positions of a profile, including past ones and somehow it still does not work.

I only manage to get past positions of my direct connections, then even those 2 or 3 degrees away, I only see present positions via the API even though I can see all positions via the website.

I tried the technique described here : https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/accessing-out-network-profiles also, and even for profiles which are 3 degrees away from me (so not out of network), this method keeps only returning the current positions. I used the specified headers and everything, still only current positions returned.

Could you please give me a working example of how to retrieve ALL positions for a 2 or 3 degrees connection via API, ideally REST and also Javascript ?

Is it even possible given the current API ?

I guess it should, since I can see the information via the website, it should be somehow available via API...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The API documentation for the available [Profile Fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields) list which fields are available given the relationship with the viewer. Right at the top, there is a table that states that for anyone other than 1st degree connections, with regards to position data it will only return "Current positions only":

[image]

So it looks like the public API only allows you to retrieve past positions for immediate connections.

Comment: hmm, that's quite strange since we are able to see those past positions on the website ... you said "public api", is there any other one at all ?

Comment: No, what you see is what you get.

Comment: This is no longer the case: you can only get the current position for 1st-degree connections. See the linkedin developer forum thread: https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/retrieve-all-positions-profile-including-past-ones